# Doing math with a value from readarray

Tags: arithmetic, readarray

I have some numbers that have been read in from a file, using the `readarray` package. But now I need to add two of these numbers together and output their sum into the file. Is there a way to do this within LaTeX? I'd prefer to avoid TikZ and other heavy-weight packages if possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{readarray}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
1 2
3 4
\end{filecontents}

\readdef{testdata.dat}{\mydata}
\readarray\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]

\newcommand{\plustwo}[1]{\number\numexpr#1+2\relax}

\begin{document}
I want the following to display as a number: \plustwo{\myarray[2,2]}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) where you use `readarray` to load in some numbers from a file (say, using `filecontents`), and then give an explicit example of what you want to do with them. Giving some working code to start from clarifies what you want and makes it much easier to help you - and hence much more likely that some one will.

Comment: @Andrew Does this help?

Comment: I get the expected result, that is, 6, with `filecontents*` instead of `filecontents`

Comment: @egreg D'oh! I can't believe it, but that was indeed the problem. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I agree with @egreg, your MWE seems to do what you want if you use `filecontents*`, which prevents `testdata.dat` from being given a descriptive a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `readarray` gets thoroughly confused by `filecontents` that adds a prologue to the written file

```
%% LaTeX2e file `testdata.dat'
%% generated by the `filecontents' environment
%% from source `draconis' on 2018/10/23.
%%
1 2
3 4
```

and issues an error.

```
! Package listofitems Error: Empty list ignored, nothing to do.
```

With `filecontents*` the prologue is not written out and everything works as expected.